# Fluent mongo Count() performance

Tags: linq, mongodb

Given this wrapper:

```
    public MongoCollection<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        var query = DataBase.GetCollection<TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name + "s");
        return query;
    }

    public long Count<TEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria) where TEntity : class
    {
        return this.GetQuery<TEntity>().AsQueryable().Count(criteria);
    }
```

If I call Count(), will the query be performed on the server as stated in the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bcount%28%29%7D%7D)?

```
var count = db<MyEntity>.Count(x => x.Foo = "foo");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It will get executed server-side.  You can verify this by turning the profiling up on your mongodb server and seeing what gets executed.

Comment: Thank you for the fast turnaround!